# Python tkinter after method not working as expected

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to learn Tkinter module, but I can't undestand why the after method doesn't behave as expected. From what I know, it should wait ms milliseconds and then execute the function, but in my case the function gets executed many more time, not considering the time I write. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def doSomething():
    x = int(l["text"])
    l["text"] = str(x + 1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
l = Label(root, text="0")
l.pack()

while True:
    l.after(1000, doSomething)
    root.update()
    if int(l["text"]) >= 5:
        break

root.mainloop()
```

After the first 2 seconds the label starts displaying humongous numbers

Comment: What is the purpose of `while True`, instead, you can move your `if` and `root.after()` inside the func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the first 2 seconds the label starts displaying humongous numbers

Keep in mind, `while True`, is an infinite loop, you are making infinite calls to `root.after()` means alot of events are being scheduled to be called after 1 second. Better way to do this is to remove your `while` and move it all inside your function.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def doSomething():
    x = int(l["text"])
    l["text"] = x + 1
    if int(l["text"]) < 5: # Only repeat this function as long as this condition is met
        l.after(1000, doSomething)

root.geometry("300x300")
l = Label(root, text="0")
l.pack()

doSomething()

root.mainloop()
```

Though the best way to write the function would be to create a variable and increase the value of that variable inside the function and then show it out:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

count = 0 # Initial value
def doSomething():
    global count # Also can avoid global by using parameters
    count += 1 # Increase it by 1 
    l['text'] = count # Change text
    if count < 5:
        l.after(1000, doSomething)

root.geometry("300x300")
l = Label(root, text=count)
l.pack()

doSomething() # If you want a delay to call the function initially, then root.after(1000,doSomething)

root.mainloop()
```

This way you can reduce the complexity of your code too and make use of the variable effectively and avoid nasty type castings ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I guess the best way to call after  is inside a function, so that it can be executed as long as a certain condition is met, right? Because I don't understand why using the while True loop is a bad idea in this case. I get that i'm making infinite calls, but why isn't the method executing one call per second, as stated in the after(1000, doSomething)?

Comment: @FraSassone `while` does not wait 1 second for `doSomething` to get executed. As long as `while` is concerned, `root.after()` is just a line of code that does not stop it. One way to pause `while` in between is to use `time.sleep()` but it also has its disadvantages, always better to use `after()` and avoid `while` at all costs.

Comment: @FraSassone ~ Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer if this answered your questions correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I'm new here, thanks for the clarification <3

Answer (score 1):

You are using infinite loop when using while True. Correct way is:

```
from tkinter import *

def doSomething():
    x = int(l["text"])
    l["text"] = str(x + 1)
    if x < 5:
        l.after(1000, doSomething)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
l = Label(root, text="0")
l.pack()


doSomething()


root.mainloop()
```